# TChart: Изменение лейблов в TopAxis

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, teechart

Каким изменить надписи у стандартного TChart'а на верху (или снизу)? Дело в том, что гистограмма формируется только по оси y:

[image: Series1.AddY(Mas[x, 1]);]

, а для x нужно указать просто подписи из массива данных Mas[x,0]. 
Скриншот того, что надо в итоге получить (наименования столбцов) - данные произвольны: 
[image: Goal]

Comment: Что на скриншоте нужно оставить  - 0 1 2 или  5 8 12?

Comment: На скрине сверху выделено красным то (0, 1, 2, ... 7), что надо заменить на свои данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Убрать `Series Mark Visible`.
 Добавлять нужные значения как марки столбиков в `AddBar` и указать
 `LabelStyle talMark`   (в TC Std в Rio это есть, про D7 не знаю)

2) При необходимости большей свободы обрабатывать `OnGetAxisLabel`

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for var i := 0 to 4 do
    Series1.AddBar(1+ Random(6), '', clRed);
  Chart1.BottomAxis.LabelStyle := talText;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1GetAxisLabel(Sender: TChartAxis; Series: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer; var LabelText: string);
begin
  if (Sender = Chart1.BottomAxis) and (Series = Series1) then
    LabelText := XMas[ValueIndex]
end;
```